# If $f(x)=K^x$, then which of the following is not true?

Tags: logic

> If $f(x) = K^x$, then which of the following is not true?
> (A) $f(x) f(-x) = 1$.
> (B) $f(x + 3) f(x - 3) = (f(x))^2$. 
> (C) $f(x + 3) - 3 f(x + 2) + 3 f(x + 2) f(-1) - f(x) f(0)= (K - 1)^3 f(x)$.
> (D) All of the previous choices are true

I checked the options (A),(B),(C) and found that they are **true**.

But I had also covered the topics "Logical Deductions & Connectives".
So, **technically speaking** shouldn't option (D) be:

> All of the previous choices are false **$\qquad$OR**
> At least one of the previous choices are false

Comment: You're overthinking it. If this is a multiple choice exam, as an answer like (D) would indicate, then only one choice is meant to be correct and "at least one of the previous answers is false" would mean to mark that answer instead. The context of the question really matters.

Comment: @PrincessEev since the question (not options) asks us to mark that option which is not true then considering the things we are supposed to know, I think, Option (D) in its present state should be incorrect. Though, this would also mean that the question itself is invalid and so if one comes across it, will have to be skipped as none of the options are false.

Comment: Usually, on a multiple-choice test, an option such as (D) would read "All of the above" or "None of the above". However since the question is (as you point out) already asking which option is *not* true, these would have been even more so unacceptably ambiguous: should "None of the above" mean that none of the other answers is true? Or that none of the other answers is not true? Thus, I read (D) as a pragmatic way to mitigate that ambiguity in context, i.e. by wording it as a complete phrase which could be thought of as apart from the logical "not" of the original question.

Comment: So, in other words, *practically speaking*: yeah, don't overthink it. But, *technically speaking*: you're right. It does say "which of the *following*", and (D) is "following", which means the "not" of the original question indeed governs (D), which means that it is also incorrect by dint of the fact that (A) (B) and (C) are all true, making (D) true and thus not "not true". You should point it out to the instructor--that is, if you think he/she has the sort of sense of humor to be amused & not annoyed by a little lighthearted pedantry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If $f(x) = K^x$, then which of the following is not true?
> >  (A) $f(x) f(-x) = 1$.
> >  (B) $f(x + 3) f(x - 3) = (f(x))^2$. 
> >  (C)$f(x + 3) - 3 f(x + 2) + 3 f(x + 2) f(-1) - f(x) f(0)= (K - 1)^3
> > f(x)$.
> >   (D) All of the previous choices are true
>
> I checked the options (A),(B),(C) and found that they are **true**.

If options A,B,C are indeed all true, then none of the four options is *not true*, that is, this exercise has no correct answer.

> I wonder how the question-setter may tackle this problem, do you have any ideas?

If options A,B,C are indeed all true, then the cleanest offer for option D to be the required choice is just “one option above is false”. Notice that even though this offer is ambiguous (does “one” mean at least or exactly one?), it is *not true* in either case.

> So, **technically speaking** shouldn't option (D) be
>
> All of the previous choices are false **OR** At least one of the previous choices are false

If options A,B,C are indeed all true, then yes, this option is indeed *not true*.

Your “technically speaking” clause is inaccurate, since there are multiple ways of righting option D (making its truth value $0$).

P.S. I’ve qualified every paragraph with “ If options A,B,C are indeed all true” because I don’t know this to be the case: for example, for $K=0,$ equality A is undefined and arguably *not true*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1. Also, I wonder how the question-setter may tackle this problem, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check out the expanded answer.